# What is Zone.js and core-js thing in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have been using angular 2 from last year but I did not get answer why we are using zone.js and core js in angular 2 file?
Can anyone explain in details in your own word?

Answer (score 2):

[core.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) includes polyfills to be able to use new features that are not available in all browsers yet and still make the code run on these browsers.

zone.js is the basis for all change detection in Angular.
It wraps all Angular code in a scope where async calls like `addEventListener`, `setTimeout`, ... are patched so that Angular gets notified when they are completed. Angular runs change detection automatically every time such an async call is completed.
This allows it to reduce change detection cycles to the absolute minimum.